# Groovy Compilation error :Unrecognized Windows Sockets error

Tags: groovy, jenkins, gradle, easyb

**Environment :**
Jenkins Server (Linux)
Senkins slave agent (Windows )
Build :Gradle
Project : EasyB ,Selenium,Groovy

I am getting a compilation error while trying to compile my easyB + selenium project.
We use gradle to manage the project.

The projects compiles fine on local desktop, but fails when we try to compile it via a Jenkins job - using a windows slave agent, it throws a compilation error.
The error is bit cryptic- ***`java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 10106: socket`***

Grails users have reported a similar problem- which they attributed to overuse of a port. But that cant be the case in this situation ?

I wonder if Gradle is trying to download stuff ? 
But that also doesn't make too much sense - since the compilation runs fine- if I run it when logged in directly to the windows slave agent machine.

**Compilation error**

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':compileGroovy'.
         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:68)
         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:34)
         at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.CacheLockHandlingTaskExecuter$1.run(CacheLockHandlingTaskExecuter.java:34)
         at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess$2.create(DefaultCacheAccess.java:200)
         at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:172)
         at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:198)
         at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.longRunningOperation(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:137)
         at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:83)
         at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.CacheLockHandlingTaskExecuter.execute(CacheLockHandlingTaskExecuter.java:32)
         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:55)
         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:57)
         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:41)
         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:51)
         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:52)
         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:42)
         at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:247)
         at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.executeTask(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:192)
         at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.doExecute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:177)
         at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:83)
         at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:36)
         at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
         at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
         at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
         at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter$1.run(TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter.java:31)
         at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess$1.create(DefaultCacheAccess.java:111)
         at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:126)
         at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:109)
         at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:129)
         at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:79)
         at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter.execute(TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter.java:29)
         at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
         at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
         at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
         at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
         at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
         at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:54)
         at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:155)
         at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:110)
         at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:78)
         at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:38)
         at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessGradleLauncherActionExecuter.execute(InProcessGradleLauncherActionExecuter.java:39)
         at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessGradleLauncherActionExecuter.execute(InProcessGradleLauncherActionExecuter.java:25)
         at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:50)
         at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ActionAdapter.execute(ActionAdapter.java:30)
         at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ActionAdapter.execute(ActionAdapter.java:22)
         at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:200)
         at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:173)
         at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
         at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:138)
         at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
         at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
         at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:48)
         at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
         at org.gradle.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:39)
         at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:50)
         at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:32)
         at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:26)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException: java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 10106: socket
         at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:39)
         at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.TcpIncomingConnector.accept(TcpIncomingConnector.java:66)
         at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.HandshakeIncomingConnector.accept(HandshakeIncomingConnector.java:45)
         at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.DefaultMultiChannelConnector.accept(DefaultMultiChannelConnector.java:57)
         at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.DefaultMessagingServer.accept(DefaultMessagingServer.java:43)
         at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultWorkerProcessFactory$DefaultWorkerProcessBuilder.build(DefaultWorkerProcessFactory.java:77)
         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.daemon.CompilerDaemonManager.startDaemon(CompilerDaemonManager.java:92)
         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.daemon.CompilerDaemonManager.getDaemon(CompilerDaemonManager.java:52)
         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.daemon.DaemonGroovyCompiler.execute(DaemonGroovyCompiler.java:47)
         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.daemon.DaemonGroovyCompiler.execute(DaemonGroovyCompiler.java:34)
         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingGroovyCompiler.delegateAndHandleErrors(NormalizingGroovyCompiler.java:99)
         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingGroovyCompiler.execute(NormalizingGroovyCompiler.java:48)
         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingGroovyCompiler.execute(NormalizingGroovyCompiler.java:34)
         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.DelegatingGroovyCompiler.execute(DelegatingGroovyCompiler.java:29)
         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.DelegatingGroovyCompiler.execute(DelegatingGroovyCompiler.java:20)
         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.IncrementalJavaCompilerSupport.execute(IncrementalJavaCompilerSupport.java:33)
         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.IncrementalJavaCompilerSupport.execute(IncrementalJavaCompilerSupport.java:23)
         at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.GroovyCompile.compile(GroovyCompile.java:77)
         at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject$MetaClassAdapter.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:196)
         at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:102)
         at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDynamicObject.invokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:99)
         at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.GroovyCompile_Decorated.invokeMethod(Unknown Source)
         at org.gradle.util.ReflectionUtil.invoke(ReflectionUtil.groovy:23)
         at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$4.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:150)
         at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$4.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:145)
         at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:472)
         at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:461)
         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:60)
         ... 57 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 10106: socket
         at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.TcpIncomingConnector.accept(TcpIncomingConnector.java:61)
         ... 83 more
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that error is a [WSAEPROVIDERFAILEDINIT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#WSAEPROVIDERFAILEDINIT) error.  From the link:

> **Service provider failed to initialize.**
>   The requested service provider could not be loaded or initialized. This error is returned if either a service provider's DLL could not be loaded (LoadLibrary failed) or the provider's WSPStartup or NSPStartup function failed.

This might be caused by Java being launched by a wrapper, but not [receiving all the correct environment variables](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?346139-socket%28%29-error-10106-%28WSAEPROVIDERFAILEDINIT%29&p=1179837#post1179837):

> A quick search over at Sun's Java site (for "10106") turned up this thread: "java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 10106: create" at http://forum.java.sun.com/thread.jsp...hreadID=329241
>
> The thread seems to suggest that your environment variable for "system root" might be incorrect, and that it needs to be reset. Or, as an alternative, you can set/select "Append Environment to Native Environment"

(Note, that link is dead, this one works though: [Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 10106: create](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2196731))

So, I guess look into seeing how Jenkins is being launched.